# Javadoc missing problem..!

Tags: netbeans, javadoc

I am designing a chat messenger using Java.

I need to use the cryptography extensions found in `javax.crypto.*` and `java.security.*`. The Javadoc viewer of NetBeans works fine with most methods in these packages. But some methods<sup>*</sup> will not display the Javadoc:

> Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager.

How do I solve missing Javadoc?

<sup>*</sup>Specifically, `AlgorithmParameters.init()` and `Cipher.init()` are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods have multiple overloads. Could it be caused by NetBeans not knowing which variant you want to see information for?

Comment: I dont think it might be that.. I tried executing it on terminal, it works properly now.

Comment: But the new problem arises here is that.. I am getting a BadPaddingException because on sender client's side i convert string to bytes, encrypt this byte array, using doFinal method, then convert it back to String, and send it to server,on the other end of client i get a string, convert it back to bytes and decrypt it using doFinal method and again convert it back to String and then display it on textpane..But this gives BadPaddingException. How do i deal with this problem now..??

Comment: What does this have to do with javadoc not showing in NetBeans? Anyway, I don't know the crypto APIs.